# Db2 locate_in_string equivalent in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, db2, migration

while migration from DB2 to PostgreSQL, i found some views using db2's `locate_in_string()` function, which returns the position of a specified instance of a given substring.

For example:

```
LOCATE_IN_STRING('aaabaabbaaaab','b',1,3); -- returns 8, for the 3d instance of 'b'
LOCATE_IN_STRING('aaabaabbaaaab','b',1,1); -- returns 4, for the 1st instance of 'b'
```

Unfortunately PostgreSQLs function `position()` gives me only the position for the first instance.

I didn't find something similar in PostgreSQL.

Is there any alternative or workaround (maybe regex?)?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a different method, this is rather brute force.

It splits the string based on the pattern you are looking for.  It then adds up the length of the pieces:

```
select v.*,
       (select coalesce(sum(length(el)), 0) + count(*) * length(v.splitter)
        from unnest( (regexp_split_to_array(v.val, v.splitter))[1:v.n] ) el
       ) as pos
from (values ('aaabaabbaaaab', 3, 'b'), ('aaabaabbaaaab', 1, 'b')
     ) v(val, n, splitter);
```